# I want to extract article text and article title from list of URL's

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I need help with the use of `BeautifulSoup`. How do I extract `article text` and `article title` from a list of URLs?  Here is my current state of the code::

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    j = df.iloc[i].values
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(j[0],headers = headers)#loading text in url
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')#parsing url text
    content = soup.findAll(attrs = {'class':'td-post-content'})#extracting only text part
    content = content[0].text
    title = soup.findAll(attrs = {'class':'entry-title'})#extracting title of website
    #title = title[16].text
    print(content)
```

But I get Index error , Can anyone help ?

Comment: you may want to properly format your question's code

Comment: At which line do you get index error? Please check for array length before accessing a specific index.

Comment: content = content[0].text  at this line

Comment: Access the array elements only it is not empty. Use checks like `if content:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some checks and error handling in your code.

```py
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    j = df.iloc[i].values
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(j[0],headers = headers)#loading text in url

    if page.status_code != 200 or not page.content:
        cMsg = '' if page.content else 'Empty content - '
        print(f'{cMsg}{page.status_code} {page.reason} - with url {j[0]}')
        break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')#parsing url text
    content = soup.findAll(attrs = {'class':'td-post-content'})#extracting only text part

    # empty content if not td-post-content found
    content = content[0].text if len(content) > 0 else '' 

    title = soup.findAll(attrs = {'class':'entry-title'})#extracting title of website
    #title = title[16].text
    print(content)
```

Before getting `soup`, this checks whether your request worked, and then for `content`, it only tries to get the text if `findAll` returned anything at all - otherwise it just sets as `''`; this avoids the index error.

If `findAll` *should* be returning something, you should set a `break` at this point as well and examine your `soup` and/or `page.content` - you might not be getting the html you are expecting. While blockers should trigger the `if page.status_code != 200` part, many sites require login, or require you to confirm some thing/s or render parts of the page dynamically with js, so that data would be missing from the request response...